# How do I refer an impedance from the delta side of a transformer to the WYE side?

Tags: transformer, impedance, y-to-delta

My question is regarding the simple arrangement below:
[image]

It is simply a three phase source feeding a load through Z1, followed by an ideal WYE DELTA transformer, followed by Z2.

My question is how do I refer the impedance Z2 to the left hand side?

Comment: It depends on what Z2 connects to and your drawing doesn't show that.

Comment: Z2 connects to a three phase load

Comment: 3 phase impedance transfer functions are easily found on the web. Have you tried?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Im not looking for a transfer function, Im just looking how to simply refer the impedance to from the secondary side to the primary side.